# how can i use weight by information gain ratio operator and select attribute Operator in rapidminer at the same time

Tags: rapidminer

I am working in rapidMiner. i have an select attribute operator in order to select some of my important features. Also, it is important for me to rank the features that are used in the select attribute operator. So i used weight by information gain ratio operator with my test data which has label and i select those features that i selected in select attribute operator. now i don't know how should i connect them to k-Means clustering.

[image]

Comment: inlining the image

Comment: Do you want to scale the attributes based on the weights that were determined using the `Weight by Information Gain Ratio` operator?